# Accepting larger numbers with decimal values in C

Tags: c, double, structure

I'm writing a code that allows the user to add employees by ID, age and salary however, for salary I'm not sure what value to use in order to scanf and printf a number such as 78950.86. I used double for SALARY because there are more values to hold and I've tried playing around with the printf and scanf for this variable, but it I either get segmentation faults or random numbers. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 2
// Define Number of Employees "SIZE" to be 2

 struct Employee{
    int ID;
    int AGE;
    double SALARY;
};
//Declare Struct Employee


 /* main program */
int main(void) {

    int option = 0;
    int i;
    struct Employee emp[SIZE];

    printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");

    // Declare a struct Employee array "emp" with SIZE elements
    // and initialize all elements to zero

    do {
            // Print the option list
            printf("1. Display Employee Information\n");
            printf("2. Add Employee\n");
            printf("0. Exit\n\n");
            printf("Please select from the above options: ");

            // Capture input to option variable
            scanf("%d",&option);
            printf("\n");

            switch (option) {
                    case 0: // Exit the program

                            break;
                    case 1: // Display Employee Data
                            // @IN-LAB

                          printf("EMP ID EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
                          printf("====== ======= ==========\n");

                          //Use "%6d%9d%11.21f" formatting in a
                          //printf statement to display
                          //employee id, age and salary of
                          //all employees using a loop construct

               for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
                                  printf("%d    %d     %11.2lf", emp[i].ID, emp[i].AGE, emp[i].SALARY);
                          }

                          //The loop construct will be run for SIZE times
                          //and will only display Employee data
                          //where the EmployeeID is > 0

                          break;
                  case 2: //Adding Employee
                                    // @IN-LAB

                          printf("Adding Employee\n");
                          printf("===============\n");

                          for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {

                          printf("\nEnter employee ID: ");
                          scanf ("%d", &emp[i].ID);

                          printf("\nEnter employee Age: ");
                          scanf ("%d", &emp[i].AGE);

                          printf("\nEnter employee Salary: ");
                          scanf ("%11lf", &emp[i].SALARY);
                                  }


                          //Check for limits on the array and add employee
                          //data accordingly

                          break;

                  default:

                          printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");

            }

    } while (option!= 0);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `scanf ("%ld.%02d\n", &emp[i].SALARY);` regularly generates a warning on many compilers.  Insure your compiler warnings are fully enabled.

Comment: A fundamental property of floating point variables with a binary mantissa (which is all existing floating point representations) is that they cannot exactly represent values like `0.1` or `0.01` - which means using them to represent currency always includes an error, which tends to propagate through calculations.   You could try using a structure that represents major and minor units (like dollars and cents) using two integers.   Reading two integers separated by a `'.'` is trivial - just make sure the integral types you choose have  sufficient range for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your format strings are using `%ld.%02d` when dealing with a `double`, which says to treat it as 2 integers separated by a period (which should have generated warnings).  Fix the string to properly indicate one `double`, or if (as @MalcomMcLean suggests) you want to keep dollars and cents separately, use a different field/variable for each.

Comment: If you store amounts of money, store the number of cents, even if you use double type. Accountants care about odd pennies because it's a fraud check.

Comment: Updated to show the answer I was looking for. The problem I was having was that scanf cannot register the decimal value, which was leading to errors. Also, I only needed to round to two decimals, but the suggestion to store dollars and cents as two separate variables is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm not sure what value to use in order to scanf and printf a number such as 78950.86."

Generally speaking, Salaries are not really "Large Numbers", in the world of Coding(or C data types, to be precise). For the example you have quoted even a single precision float data type will be sufficient. (Search for "max finite positive value in single precision" in the pagehttps://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

So the double data type you used is more than sufficient for the said purpose. As rightly pointed out by Scott, the segmentation faults are being caused because your format string suggests 2 data parameters, when there is only 1 double data type variable.

My opinion would be not to store salary data as separate dollars and cents. From the employer's perspective these cents are going to add up to dollars and they will eventually be merged with the dollar data, making your summation algorithm complicated.

In conclusion, you can use a double data type for salary variable. When printing salary, you can use "%.2f" in the format string. When using scanf to get salary in normal fixed point notation, you can use "%lf" in the format string.